# MVC 4 Web Api 404

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api2

I have looked all over for some kind of soultion for this and it seems I have it setup correctly and followed all corrections in other questions.

When calling "http://localhost/en/api/cart/get" I get:

```
{"Message":"No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost/en/api/cart/get'.","MessageDetail":"No type was found that matches the controller named 'cart'."}
```

...when trying to access a ApiController setup in an EPiServer CMS/Commerce 7.5+ solution.

The Controller looks like this:

```
public class CartController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    public string Get()
    {
        return "OK";
    }
}
```

In Global.asax.cs i have this:

```
protected void Application_Start()
    {
        RegisterApis(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
```

And the RegisterAPis looks like this:

```
public static void RegisterApis(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
         "Api", // Route name 
         "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters 
         new { id = RouteParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults 
        );

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
         "LanguageAwareApi", // Route name 
         "{language}/api/{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters 
         new { id = RouteParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );

        // We only support JSON
        var appXmlType = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.XmlFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.FirstOrDefault(t => t.MediaType == "application/xml");
        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.XmlFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Remove(appXmlType);
    }
```

On the same machine I have the EPiServer Commerce starterkit running i IIS and the code for registering the api controllers is the same. That site runs fine and the api calls can be made correctly but on my site all I get is 404.

So I am probably missing some configuration but I can't for my life figure out what it is. The weird part is that on my site I'm running the EPiServer ServiceApi which creates the /episerverapi Web Api mapping and that works just fine.

Anyone got any clues on why I can't get my APiControllers to work?

Answer (score 1):

In Web API the http verb help the framework to find the right action to be executed and return a result. For sample, in a case of a `get` method, you just call the controller by `get` http verb:

```
http://localhost/en/api/cart
```

It will bind a `Get` action method in the `Cart` controller class. It is valid for a `Post`, `Put`, `Delete` methods too. Keep the default route of asp.net web api

```
routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "API Default",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

Comment: Calling /en/api/cart gives me a whole other 404, the address changes to http://localhost/404-page-not-found?aspxerrorpath=%2fen%2fapi%2fcart

Changing the methodname to GetStatus and calling http://localhost/en/api/cart/getStatus/ I get the regular No type was found that matches the controller named 'cart'

Comment: Try keeping the default route of asp.net web api.

Comment: Which is the default route you mean?

Comment: I've posted it on my awnser Actually, it is the route that comes from on the asp.net mvc template.

Answer (score 0):

Try calling just

```
http://localhost/en/api/cart
```

In WebAPI if the name of the method matches a HTTP verb then it calls that method when that verb is used on that controller.